# How to prevent that a windows called by pyautoit is closed after script is finished?

Tags: python-2.7, autoit

example:

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3) 
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
```

The example opens notepad, writes "hello World" but after that, noteped is closed inmediatly again. How can I achieve that notepad stays open?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it should not close itself. But lets do some troubleshooting.

Keep the Script active with a sleep(in ms). Does it still close itself?

```
Sleep(10000)
```

If it does remove the last line. If it doesn't, then there is something wrong with this line of code.

```
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
```

Tell me what results you've got.